# Why was this upvote marked as `+50` in the profile page?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, up-votes

From [this profile page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1810/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation&StartDate=2022-04-01%2022:07:11Z&sort=time) ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20220501232237/https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1810/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation&StartDate=2022-04-01+22%3A07%3A11Z&sort=time), [mirror 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FwCo.png)) :

[image]

Why was this upvote marked as `+50` in the profile page?

Comment: I can't find the original, but I've seen this asked before a few times.